# Firebase observer setting values initially, but not updating when changes are made

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to set up a function to listen for changes within a certain part of my database:

```
private func observeParticipants() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomID).child("participants")
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        print("observe snapshot.value: \(snapshot.value)")
        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

            for each in snapDict {

                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                print("\n\navatarDictionary:\n \(self.avatarDictionary)")
                print("\nhandleDictionary:\n \(self.handleDictionary)")
                print("\ngenderDictionary:\n \(self.genderDictionary)")
                print("\nnameDictionary:\n \(self.nameDictionary)")
                print("\nstatusDictionary:\n \(self.statusDictionary)")
                self.navBarCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

When I run this, it loads the correct values, but if I make a change, for example add a new user to the group, it doesn't reflect that change. The database is updated fine, but the observer isn't seeing that. Is there any way I can re-write this to make is observe properly? I can post my database structure if it will help.

Thanks!

EDIT: Database structure:

https://pastebin.com/SZ2mE2Vt

EDIT: snapshot.value after adding second user:

```
Snapshot.value: Optional({
    gender = female;
    handle = sav;
    name = Savina;
    profilePicture = "https://graph.facebook.com/1929991317219760/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1";
    status = F8B016;
})
```

EDIT 2:

This is the code that works for fetching all user values initially, and also every time I leave the view and come back. It just doesn't act properly as an observer, i.e. if I add a participant, it doesn't see that and update the necessary values such as the collection view. I have to leave the view and come back for that to happen.

```
func getParticipantInfo() {

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomIdGlobal)
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

            for each in snapDict {

                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                print("\n\navatarDictionary:\n \(self.avatarDictionary)")
                print("\nhandleDictionary:\n \(self.handleDictionary)")
                print("\ngenderDictionary:\n \(self.genderDictionary)")
                print("\nnameDictionary:\n \(self.nameDictionary)")
                print("\nstatusDictionary:\n \(self.statusDictionary)")
                self.navBarCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you post your database structure?

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/SZ2mE2Vt

Comment: If  currentRoomId is the childByAutoID that you have just bellow "groups" I think you should observe "participants". Give it a try!

Comment: I mean let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomID).child("participants")

Comment: Adding `.child("participants")` after the `.child(currentRoomID)` results in a crash, unexpectedly found nil on the first value in the loop (`let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String`)

Comment: Ok, print only the snapshot value to see what your snap looks like and then you can't fetch the data according by the new value.

Comment: Ok I printed the snapshot.value and it printed my user info (I'm the only one in that chat room currently). gender = male;
`    handle = TestHandleOne;
    name = Timothy;
    profilePicture = "https://graph.facebook.com/1682119565138679/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1";
    status = 2FCB78;`

Comment: So it works fine, now you only have to retrieve the uid of each participant and fetch the data. I'm on the phone now so not sure if the code will work but it should be something like: if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] { for each in dict { if let user = each.value as? [String: Any] { print(user["name"] as! String) } } }

Comment: That actually sounds a lot like I have now, is there a difference I'm not seeing?

Comment: The difference is you now observing the participants child.

Comment: Sorry, I should have updated my question - When I added he "participants" child, I didn't change any of the other code so it's all still done the same way - I updated my question with my current code. Sorry if I'm still missing something!

Comment: Hmm, can you post the exact snapshot?

Comment: Better add new user there and then post the snapshot

Comment: Instead of using .reloadData(), can you try navBarCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath])? I'm thinking the collection view might not be updating the number of items. I use a similar structure for adding messages in a chat app.

Comment: Hey Jen! Thanks for the suggestion about adding a groups node, as you can see I did just that! I just tried your suggestion here and got an error on "IndexPath". Error: `Cannot convert value of type '[IndexPath].Type' (aka 'Array<IndexPath>.Type') to expected argument type '[IndexPath]'`

Comment: @i6x86 After adding a second user, printing snapshot.value prints only the second user's values. Posted snapshot at the bottom of my question.

Comment: and you've checked, just to be sure, there are 2 users in "participants"?

Comment: In Firebase? Yep there are definitely 2 participants. The code (without `.child("participants")`) works fine to grab all participants info the first time around, but it simply doesn't act as an observer, so when I add a new participant, the values such as the navBarCollectionView aren't updated. I I leave the view and come back, they are. But I need the observer to listen for new users being added and update immediately.

Comment: Con you confirm, all this above is your actual code?

Comment: I edited my question, posting the code that works (upon the view loading, not as an observer) at the bottom. Note that I made a small change and `currentRoomID` is now `currentRoomIdGlobal`. However that doesn't affect the core problem.

Comment: I see... Let's reload the data asynchronous then. Put it between this DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: Put the function call (in `viewDidLoad`) inside the dispatch block? Or the code within the function?

Comment: just reload the data asynchronous. DispatchQueue.main.async { self.navBarCollectionView.reloadData() }

Comment: Ok, tried it. Same issue - have to leave the view and come back for the collection view to display the new user